# How to modify the orders or methods in IDEA quickly?

Tags: intellij-idea

In eclipse, we can drag methods to change the orders of methods in the outline view. But I can't find similar function in IDEA.

There is a "structure" view in IDEA, but which is not allowed to drag the methods. I have to change the  orders in the source file.

Is it possible to do it in IDEA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the cursor is on method definition line, e.g:

```
public String toString() {
```

you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow up/down</kbd> to move the whole method up or down.

To make things simplier you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> first.
This will collapse all methods, allowing you to rearrange them much faster with previously mentioned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow up/down</kbd> .